# Xammp port issue

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

When i start any web project in netbeans it start tomcat in xammp by dfault but when tomcat is in running state Mysql(php admin) page not open i think there is some kind of port issue please guide me about this issue

change pot mo in config files

Answer (score 0):

Find out what ever the port that error cause and you can kill that usage by following theses steps. Here I take **3325** as my port.

1. Open cmd and type **netstat -ano | findstr 3325**.

[image]

2. Then type this code with what ever the output that you gets. Here I get **10360** as my output for the 1st one. **taskkill /F /pid 10360**

[image]

Using this method you can kill the process of port that already in use. Kill the relevant process that is not needed if there are multiple processes hang on this port. This might be helpful to fix your issue.